# undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass + after login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm getting this error after hitting login
my full trace is

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #20):


 def create
  @session = Session.new(params[:session], request.remote_ip)
   if @session.valid?
    set_current_user(@session.current_user)
    add_to_current_cart params



Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/models/session.rb:12:in `initialize'
app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:20:in `new'
app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:20:in `create'
Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
  "authenticity_token"=>==",
"email"=>{"{:placeholder=>\"email@address.com\",
:tabIndex=>\"1\",
\"class\"=>\"\"}"=>""},
"password"=>"[FILTERED]",
"commit"=>"Log In"}
```

My sessions controller file is

```
 def create
  @session = Session.new(params[:session], request.remote_ip)
   if @session.valid?
  set_current_user(@session.current_user)
  add_to_current_cart params
  add_to_favorites params

  if session[:return_to]
    redirect_to session[:return_to]
  else
```

Session.rb file is

```
  class Session
 INCORRECT_PASSWORD = "The password you entered is incorrect.       Please try again (make sure your caps lock is off)."
 EMAIL_NOT_FOUND = "The email id you entered does not belong to any   account."
 MANDATORY_FIELDS = "You must fill in all of the fields"

include ActiveModel::Validations
attr_accessor :email, :password, :errors
attr_reader :current_user

 def initialize(params={}, ip_address=nil)
   @errors = ActiveModel::Errors.new(self)
   @email = params[:email]
   @password = params[:password]
   @current_user = User.find_by_email(@email)
   @ip_address = ip_address
end

 def valid?
mandatory_fields_presence
if @current_user && @errors.empty?
  if @current_user.waiting_for_confirmation?
    email_confirmation_link = "/account/#{@current_user.uuid}/send-confirmation-email"
    @errors.add(:base, "Please confirm your account first. <a href='#{email_confirmation_link}'>Resend confirmation link</a>")
  end
end
authenticate if @errors.empty?
@current_user.signed_in(@ip_address) if @errors.empty?
@errors.empty?

end

 private
  def mandatory_fields_presence
  @errors.add(:email, MANDATORY_FIELDS) if @email.blank? or        @password.blank?
  end

 def authenticate
   @errors.add(:email, EMAIL_NOT_FOUND) if @current_user.nil?
   if @errors.empty? && !@current_user.authenticated?(@password)
    @errors.add(:password, INCORRECT_PASSWORD)
 end
end

end
      if session[:login_page] == true
        redirect_to root_path
     else
        redirect_to :back
     end
    end
  else
    if session[:login_page] == true
      render :new
    else
      flash[:login_failed] = OpenStruct.new({ :errors =>  @session.errors, :login_failed => true })
      redirect_to :back
    end
  end
 end
```

Working on ruby 1.9.3, rails 4.2.5
I'm unable to login after hitting login button, even signup form is also getting this kind of issue. Help out me to fix this issue?

Comment: the parameters you are sending does not contain the `session hash`

Comment: you are sending the params wrong, check my answers on how can you send the params. pls paste the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters you are sending are incorrect, you are taking the params value as a string, which is incorrect,

**Try sending params as key and value,**

**Send Parameters as:**

```
{

    "utf8"=>"✓",
  "authenticity_token"=>"b7t1yJ7cGyxDmecBpvBrGLRbh/ubtPjsUFdP/HosK8kp/ZLRtrV3dVWE2vPjDnThCbt9hk1ftm5ZMg9Ia1StWw==",
    "email"=>{"pavanez4u@gmail.com",
    "tabIndex"=>"1",
    "password"=>"[FILTERED]"
    "commit"=>"Log In"
}
```

`@email = params[:email]` this line throws you an error because the params format is incorrect.

Comment: How to include params

Comment: Please paste the form, the form you have taken is incorrect

Comment: @Pavan Kumar, what happened?

Comment: why did you unaccepted my answer? is it wrong or what?